# Sql Server Query for Ical Recurence too slow

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, recursion, icalendar

My question today is I have a query to get all my appointement from a Ical format.
The thing is the query is very too slow because I use an Dll that i made in C# to get all occurence with the rrule from ical but I use it 2 time in my query because I do a stuff to concatenate everything from the same day together.

Here's my query:

```
    select 1,case when B.startdate is not null then B.startdate else  case when charindex('Z',dtstart) > 0 then  dbo.VCalendar_DateFormat(dtstart) else LEFT(dtstart,4) + '-' + substring(dtstart,5,2) + '-' +  substring(dtstart,7,2)end end as startTime,
C.ID as idressource,ltrim(rtrim((select STUFF(( select ' ' + CHAR(10) + Summary + ' ' + Description
                                    from tbIcal_data AA
                                    left join tbPatient D on (replacE(replacE(replacE(Summary,' ',''),'-',''),'_','') Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI like '%' +replace(replace(replace(D.Prenom_SansAccent + D.Nom_SansAccent,' ',''),'-',''),'_','')  + '%' ) or  ( replacE(replacE(Summary,' ',''),'-','')   like '%'+ ltrim(rtrim(REPLACE(REPLACE(isnull(D.TelephoneDomicile,'')+isnull(D.TelephoneTravail,'')+isnull(D.TelephonePortable,''),' ',''),'-','')))  + '%' and ltrim(rtrim(REPLACE(REPLACE(isnull(D.TelephoneDomicile,'')+isnull(D.TelephoneDomicile,'')+isnull(D.TelephonePortable,''),' ',''),'-',''))) <> '')
                                    outer apply dbo.ExpandRecurrence(RRule,null,0,GETDATE(),dateadd(year,2,getdate()),case when charindex('Z',AA.dtstart) > 0 then  dbo.VCalendar_DateFormat(AA.dtstart) else LEFT(AA.dtstart,4) + '-' + substring(AA.dtstart,5,2) + '-' +  substring(AA.dtstart,7,2)end,case when charindex('Z',AA.dtEnd) > 0 then  dbo.VCalendar_DateFormat(AA.dtEnd) else LEFT(AA.dtEnd,4) + '-' + substring(AA.dtEnd,5,2) + '-' +  substring(AA.dtEnd,7,2)end ) BB
                                    where ((case when bb.startdate is not null then bb.startdate else  case when charindex('Z',AA.dtstart) > 0 then  dbo.VCalendar_DateFormat(AA.dtstart) else LEFT(AA.dtstart,4) + '-' + substring(AA.dtstart,5,2) + '-' +  substring(AA.dtstart,7,2)end end >= GETDATE()
                                            and datediff(day,case when bb.startdate is not null then bb.startdate else  case when charindex('Z',AA.dtstart) > 0 then dbo.VCalendar_DateFormat(AA.dtstart) else LEFT(AA.dtstart,4) + '-' + substring(AA.dtstart,5,2) + '-' +  substring(AA.dtstart,7,2)end end,case when bb.Enddate is not null then bb.Enddate else  case when charindex('Z',AA.dtEnd) > 0 then  dbo.VCalendar_DateFormat(AA.dtEnd) else LEFT(dtEnd,4) + '-' + substring(AA.dtEnd,5,2) + '-' +  substring(AA.dtEnd,7,2)end end  ) = 1) or (datediff(day,case when bb.startdate is not null then bb.startdate else  case when charindex('Z',AA.dtstart) > 0 then  dbo.VCalendar_DateFormat(AA.dtstart) else LEFT(AA.dtstart,4) + '-' + substring(AA.dtstart,5,2) + '-' +  substring(AA.dtstart,7,2)end end,case when bb.Enddate is not null then bb.Enddate else  case when charindex('Z',dtEnd) > 0 then  dbo.VCalendar_DateFormat(dtEnd) else LEFT(dtEnd,4) + '-' + substring(dtEnd,5,2) + '-' +  substring(dtEnd,7,2)end end  ) = 0
                                            and bb.StartDate is not null))
                                    and AA.ressource = A.ressource and D.ID is null and
                                    case when bb.startdate is not null then bb.startdate else  case when charindex('Z',AA.dtstart) > 0 then  dbo.VCalendar_DateFormat(AA.dtstart) else LEFT(AA.dtstart,4) + '-' + substring(AA.dtstart,5,2) + '-' +  substring(AA.dtstart,7,2)end end  = case when B.startdate is not null then B.startdate else  case when charindex('Z',A.dtstart) > 0 then  dbo.VCalendar_DateFormat(A.dtstart) else LEFT(A.dtstart,4) + '-' + substring(A.dtstart,5,2) + '-' +  substring(A.dtstart,7,2)end end 
                                    FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')AS DayMessage))) AS DayMessage
from tbIcal_data A
left join tbPatient D on (replacE(replacE(replacE(Summary,' ',''),'-',''),'_','') Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI like '%' +replace(replace(replace(D.Prenom_SansAccent + D.Nom_SansAccent,' ',''),'-',''),'_','')  + '%' ) or  ( replacE(replacE(Summary,' ',''),'-','')   like '%'+ ltrim(rtrim(REPLACE(REPLACE(isnull(D.TelephoneDomicile,'')+isnull(D.TelephoneTravail,'')+isnull(D.TelephonePortable,''),' ',''),'-','')))  + '%' and ltrim(rtrim(REPLACE(REPLACE(isnull(D.TelephoneDomicile,'')+isnull(D.TelephoneDomicile,'')+isnull(D.TelephonePortable,''),' ',''),'-',''))) <> '')
outer apply dbo.ExpandRecurrence(RRule,null,0,GETDATE(),dateadd(year,2,getdate()),case when charindex('Z',A.dtstart) > 0 then  dbo.VCalendar_DateFormat(A.dtstart) else LEFT(A.dtstart,4) + '-' + substring(A.dtstart,5,2) + '-' +  substring(A.dtstart,7,2)end,case when charindex('Z',A.dtEnd) > 0 then  dbo.VCalendar_DateFormat(A.dtEnd) else LEFT(A.dtEnd,4) + '-' + substring(A.dtEnd,5,2) + '-' +  substring(A.dtEnd,7,2)end ) B
join tbRessource C on (C.nom = A.ressource)
where ((case when B.startdate is not null then B.startdate else  case when charindex('Z',A.dtstart) > 0 then  dbo.VCalendar_DateFormat(A.dtstart) else LEFT(A.dtstart,4) + '-' + substring(A.dtstart,5,2) + '-' +  substring(A.dtstart,7,2)end end >= GETDATE()
        and datediff(day,case when B.startdate is not null then B.startdate else  case when charindex('Z',A.dtstart) > 0 then dbo.VCalendar_DateFormat(A.dtstart) else LEFT(A.dtstart,4) + '-' + substring(A.dtstart,5,2) + '-' +  substring(A.dtstart,7,2)end end,case when B.Enddate is not null then B.Enddate else  case when charindex('Z',A.dtEnd) > 0 then  dbo.VCalendar_DateFormat(A.dtEnd) else LEFT(dtEnd,4) + '-' + substring(A.dtEnd,5,2) + '-' +  substring(A.dtEnd,7,2)end end  ) = 1) or (datediff(day,case when B.startdate is not null then B.startdate else  case when charindex('Z',A.dtstart) > 0 then  dbo.VCalendar_DateFormat(A.dtstart) else LEFT(A.dtstart,4) + '-' + substring(A.dtstart,5,2) + '-' +  substring(A.dtstart,7,2)end end,case when B.Enddate is not null then B.Enddate else  case when charindex('Z',dtEnd) > 0 then  dbo.VCalendar_DateFormat(dtEnd) else LEFT(dtEnd,4) + '-' + substring(dtEnd,5,2) + '-' +  substring(dtEnd,7,2)end end  ) = 0
        and B.StartDate is not null))
and ressource <> 'Gestion' and D.ID is null
and A.Summary is not null
group by C.ID,A.ressource,case when B.startdate is not null then B.startdate else  case when charindex('Z',A.dtstart) > 0 then  dbo.VCalendar_DateFormat(A.dtstart) else LEFT(A.dtstart,4) + '-' + substring(A.dtstart,5,2) + '-' +  substring(A.dtstart,7,2)end end
```

Here some data from the table tbIcal_data:

[image]

Thank you! if you have any question feel free to leave an comment!

Comment: That's not how SO works. When you post a question you have to provide all relevant information. Right now it seems that the problem is that unspecified assembly you created but didn't post. Which you probably don't need anyway. In any case, this query is too complicated and badly formatted to make sense. Plus you don't specify the *important* stuff - the table schema, indexes and *the execution plan*. Without them one can only make guesses

Comment: My guess is that all those replacements and function calls mean the server can't use any indexes and is forced to perform multiple table scans. If you perform string replacements on a column you use for filtering or JOINs, the server *can't* use any indexes because the index contains the original, not the replaced value. The server will have to read all data, perform the replacement and then return the matching rows.

Comment: As for expanding rules, don't. You can create a table that contains all instances of the calendar rule for the next 100 years and very little space.

Comment: `charindex('Z',AA.dtstart)` on a *date*? Are you storing dates as strings perhaps? That's *another* problem. Use the *appropriate* type, eg `datetimeoffset` if you want to preserve the timezone. If you want to compare a datetime with a calendar date use `cast(myDateTimeField as date)` and compare it with a date-typed value. The server will turn it into a range query that covers the target date

Comment: `like '%' ` that forces a full table scan. You are asking for a value anywhere in the field, which means no index can be used. If you want to search free-text fields, create a full-text index and use the full text search methods

Comment: `VCalendar_DateFormat` dates have no format, they are binary values. If you import data from a file convert it to the correct type before saving it to the table.

Comment: There are so many bad things in this query it is hard to know where to start. First is those aliases. They are absolutely useless. You should use meaningful aliases instead A, B, C. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3 You don't reference most of your columns by their alias so you have no idea what table they are coming from. You have scalar and table functions all over the place, you have many nonSARGable predicates in joins and the where clause. This needs to be completely redone from the beginning.

Comment: You seem to also be storing character data in what should be date/datetime. Things like checking for charindex of 'Z' in columns named dtstart is horrific. There is just too much work here for an online forum. If I had access to all of the functions and tables I would bet this is at least a couple days work to unravel this.

Comment: What has "explain" told you about your query?